# Ninject v2+ injection dependent on parametername

Tags: c#, .net, parameters, dependency-injection, ninject

I know that with Ninject 1, it was possible to give specific instances depending on the parameter name.

E.g 
    public SomeClass(ISomething left, ISomething right)
    {}

would resolve ISomething left to the default ISomething, but ISomething right to a different binding.

How can I do this with Ninject 2+?

Note: I do not want to use [Named("XZ")], because that would force me to make the main dll of my application a dependency of Ninject. Right now I have a separate DLL CompositionRoot that depends on Ninject, and nothing else: my main dll can be used without Ninject. I would like to keep it that way.

Edit: I updated the example to use left/right instead of simple/complex after the first answer. I do not want to hardcode this dependency in my inheritance structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
Bind<ISomething >().To<LeftSomething>().When(a => a.Target.Name == "left");
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create derived interfaces `ISimpleSomething` and `IComplexSomething`?

That way you could expose additional functionality for each.

```
interface ISomething { ... }
interface IComplexSomething : ISomething { ... }
interface ISimpleSomething : ISomething { ... }
```

Comment: Because I don't want to modify my class inheritance structure just to satisfy Ninject. Maybe my example was bad, it might also be ISomething left, ISomething right; I do not want to hardcore ISomethingRight...